# Why is my menu item always showing in overflow menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-optionsmenu

The reason the overflow dots aren't showing in the screenshot is because this emulator has a menu button. But a menu press does show the item.

NerdLauncherFragment.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    … 
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    … 
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.nerd_launcher, menu);
}
```

nerd_launcher.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.nerdlauncher.nerdlauncher.NerdLauncherActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="R"
          app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

[image]

I thought for sure I had figured it out when I made the custom namespace for `showAsAction` as suggested in other answers, but my item is still stuck in the overflow menu.

Comment: Does the `Activity` your `Fragment` belongs to extend `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: @adneal That was the issue. It extended FragmentActivity. Once I changed to extend ActionBarActivity it worked fine. Post an answer if you want, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `ActionBar` to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) and setting the activity theme to `Theme.AppCompat` or a similar theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippets allow you to disable hardware menu button and show the over flow icon in action bar

in your onCreate method

```
ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                    .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
```